# Nested Associative Arrays printed as a Table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Good afternoon. I am fairly new to php and so apologise in advance if my question is a little simplistic for this forum.

I have a PHP associative array with some nested sub arrays that I wish to echo as a table. Here is the array:

```
Array 
    ( 

    [message] => Your request was executed successfully. 
    [errors] => [warnings] => Array ( ) 
    [request_timestamp] => 04-08-2016 21:43:06 
    [response_timestamp] => 04-08-2016 21:43:06 
    [request_id] => abcd1234 

    [branch] => Array 
            ( 
            [location_id] => 157499 
            ) 

    [property] => Array 
            ( 

                    [0] => Array 
                    ( 
                    [agent_ref] => WR37EF-453625 
                    [update_date] => 
                    [client_id] => 60462053 
                    [channel] => 2
                    )

                    [1] => Array 
                    ( 
                    [agent_ref] => Prop950 
                    [update_date] => 04-08-2016
                    [client_id] => 60457613 
                    [channel] => 2 
                    ) 

                    [prop2] => Array 
                    ( 
                    [agent_ref] => WR40rp-632482 
                    [update_date] => 04-08-2016
                    [client id] => 60461789 
                    [channel] => 2 
                    ) 

                    [prop3] => Array 
                    ( 
                    [agent_ref] => WR38UU-243564 
                    [update_date] => 04-08-2016
                    [id] => 60461807 
                    [channel] => 2 
                    ) 

                    [prop4] => Array 
                    (
                    [agent_ref] => WR3HMWR3HM-145622 
                    [update_date] => 04-08-2016
                    [client id] => 60462014 
                    [channel] => 2 
                    ) 
            ) 
    )
```

What I am trying [and miserably failing to achieve] is a table (preceded with a non-table Titles Area) in the following format....

**Title Area:-**

1. message: Your request was executed successfully.
2. errors: a, b, c,
3. request timestamp: 04-08-2016 21:43:06
4. response timestamp: 04-08-2016 21:43:06
5. request id: abcd1234
6. customer id: 157499

**followed by ...**

Table Design where:-

1. ..Rows are sub array names : [0] ; [1] ; [2]; [3]
2. ..Column Header Names are the sub array $keys: agent_ref; update_date; client id; channel
3. ..the row-col values are the sub array $values.

I am aware I probably need to use the foreach loop method. But getting the key-value pair out of the nested arrays in the titles/table format I need I am really struggling with.

Any help or guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid this is not a coding service. Please post the code you've tried and explain where you are stuck. This is far too much to ask for.

Comment: This is a duplicate for many other questions, these are called "multidimensional" arrays, which is what you were probably missing in your search terms. [See all of these similar questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+multidimensional+array+html+table).

Comment: Thank you for the input Jeff. And thank you for the guidance @Jeff Puckett II. It was guidance I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
extract($your_array);
echo "$message<br>";
echo "$request_id<br>"; ...etc.
..


$first=true;
echo "<table>";
foreach($property as $propkey=>$propdets) {
  if ($first) { // on first row - do headings
    $heads=array_keys($propdets); // gets the keys for headings
    echo "<tr><th>Item</th>";
    foreach($heads as $hdng) {
      echo "<th>$hdng</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  $first=false;
  echo "<tr><td>$propkey</td>"; // first column is the key(Item) - 0,1,prop2,prop3 etc.
  foreach ($propdets as $pdet) { // then loop through the details
    echo "<td>$pdet</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
...
...
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Arthur. That was much more than the guidance I was expecting. I upvoted you because you are a gentleman for providing that input - which I will study and attempt to adapt/extend. Again thank you so much.

Comment: Have now experimented with your answer Arthur and it works perfectly! Your solution has really improved my understanding of multi dimensional arrays and how to access them in the right way. I am so go grateful for your help.